# R spread across multiple value columns

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this -

```
dataset = data.frame(Site=c(rep('A',6),rep('B',6)),Date=c(rep(c('2019-05-31','2019-04-30','2019-03-31'),4)),Question=c(rep('Q1',3),rep('Q2',3)),Score=runif(12,0.5,1),Average=runif(12,0.5,1))
```

I'd like to `spread` columns in such a way that the the first two columns contain the `Site` and `Question` and the remaining columns are have the Score_Date and Average_Date

Here's an example of what the first line of the resulting table would look like

```
  Site Question Score_2019.03.31 Score_2019.04.30 Score_2019.05.31 Average_2019.03.31 Average_2019.04.30 Average_2019.05.31
   A       Q1        0.9117566        0.8661078        0.5624139          0.7246694          0.8870703          0.6401099
```

I tried using `unite` & `spread` from `tidyr` but nowhere close to the result

Any inputs would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tidyr and dplyr from the tidyverse, you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% 
  nest(Score, Average, .key = 'value_col') %>% 
  spread(key = Date, value = value_col) %>% 
  unnest(`2019-03-31`, `2019-04-30`, `2019-05-31`, .sep = "_")
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way of doing the same without hard-coding the date values? I ask because if the dates change then this won't work.

Comment: If you know you will be keeping the site and question variables, you could try the following `unnest(.preserve = c("Site", "Question"), .sep = "_")`

Comment: A quick follow-up question: I tried your solution on another dataset (same structure) and this time I got an error after `nest` saying `All nested columns must have the same number of elements.` Any idea why, and whether there's a way to overcome this? Thanks again

Comment: I'm unsure why `nest` would be causing it. You can see this error after `unnest` when the nested dataframe in one column for a particular row has a different structure than the nested dataframe in another column. For example, a 1x2 dataframe and a 1x3 dataframe. You should check this new data set a little more closely for data entry errors that would cause that kind of behavior, or post a new question with some more data.

Comment: I posted a new question here, regarding this error -
https://stackoverflow.com/q/56778160/7819673

Comment: I figured out that the error arises due to missing data in the new data frame. I'm trying to figure out whether your solution can still be used on this new dataset, or whether an alternative approach is required.