# R "unnesting" dataframe results in an error

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this -

```
dataset = data.frame(Site=c(rep('A',6),rep('B',6)),
                     Date=c(rep(c('2019-05-31','2019-04-30','2019-03-31'),4)),
                     Question=c(rep('Q1',3),rep('Q2',3)),
                     Score=runif(12,0.5,1),
                     Average=runif(12,0.5,1))
```

My objective is to spread the the `Score` and `Average` columns based on the `Date` column.

Using `tidyverse`, I manipulate the data -

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% 
  nest(Score, Average, .key = 'value_col') %>% 
  spread(key = Date, value = value_col) %>% 
  unnest(.preserve = c("Site", "Question"), .sep = "_")
```

And this results in the final dataframe I am looking for -

```
  Site Question 2019-03-31_Score 2019-03-31_Average 2019-04-30_Score 2019-04-30_Average 2019-05-31_Score 2019-05-31_Average
1    A       Q1        0.5070755          0.6948877        0.8046608          0.8359777        0.7653232          0.5259696
2    A       Q2        0.5255425          0.9482262        0.9796590          0.7612117        0.9819698          0.7710665
3    B       Q1        0.6963277          0.5416473        0.7753426          0.6710344        0.8219699          0.5310356
4    B       Q2        0.9993356          0.6293783        0.8125886          0.5007390        0.6385580          0.5238838
```

However when I add a **new site** to the original dataframe...

```
new_site= data.frame(Site=c(rep('C',4)),
                     Date=c('2019-05-31','2019-03-31','2019-05-31','2019-03-31'),
                     Question=c(rep('Q1',2),rep('Q2',2)),
                     Score=runif(4,0.5,1),
                     Average=runif(4,0.5,1))

new_dataset = rbind(dataset,new_site)
```

and re-run the data manipulation on the new dataset, I get the following error...

```
library(tidyverse)
new_dataset %>% 
  nest(Score, Average, .key = 'value_col') %>% 
  spread(key = Date, value = value_col) %>% 
  unnest(.preserve = c("Site", "Question"), .sep = "_")
```

> Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.

I figured that this is because the new site has **one day of no data.**

I'd like to know whether there's an alternate approach to treating this new dataset, and reaching the same format of output.

Comment: In your code, the assignment is not showed `<-`  Without that, `rbind(dataset,new_site)` works fine for me

Comment: The problem is not with `rbind`. It is when I run the data manipulation on the `new_dataset`. I've edited my question so it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
new_dataset %>% 
  nest(Score, Average, .key = 'value_col') %>% 
  spread(key = Date, value = value_col)
```

For the new site you haven't provided any data for the new site on `2019-03-31` and, therefore, the unnesting fails.

Better use something like

```
new_dataset %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Site, -Date, -Question) %>% 
  mutate(key = str_c(Date, "_", key)) %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!